# Android calendar recurring event multiple times per day

Tags: android, calendar

In my app I need to create a few events per day, recurring. For example.
User provides three hours: 11:30, 12:45, 15:15 and end date eg. 20-02-2017. So I need to have three events per day, repeating daily until 20-02-2017. My code is below, however it adds only last event (15:15).

```
// boxes cotnains edit fields with hours
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
    EditText e = boxes.get(i);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Calendar xd = Calendar.getInstance();
    xd.setTime(sdf.parse(e.getText().toString()));// all done
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, xd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, xd.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); 
    eventValues.put("title", "Pomiar ciśnienia");
    eventValues.put("description", "Pamiętaj aby dokonać pomiaru");
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, xd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    beginTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, xd.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    beginTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date end = sdf2.parse(etUntil.getText().toString());
    Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance();

    dt.setTime(end);

    SimpleDateFormat yyyymmdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String dtUntil = yyyymmdd.format(dt.getTime());

    long startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL="+dtUntil);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startMillis);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, startMillis + 1000*60*30);
    intent.putExtra("title", "Zmierz ciśnienie!");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

From my perspective it does not matter, if there will be three events (one per specific time) or one gathering all of them.

So far only pop-up for last time is shown and creates an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `onActivityResult` handler helped, however I do not know why.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```